# TF is broken when using robot_localization package with only IMU sensor

Tags: ros, imu

Im using this [robot_lokalization](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html) package for the linear velocity. As only sensor input in my case is IMU. I configure the parameters and set the frames as follow

```
map_frame: map             
odom_frame: odom         
base_link_frame: /thrbot/base_link 
world_frame: odom
```

The launch file is the following one

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_template.yaml" />
    <param name="odom_used" value="false"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  /thrbot/base_link /thrbot/imu_link  100" />

</launch>
```

The robot base_link frame is `thrbot/base_link` the IMU is `thrbot/imu_link`

Here is the photo of the TF without using the package

[image: TF of the robot without the package]. As can see TF is good. But when using the package my TF is broken as can see here [image: Broken TF] . Any help how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What did your launch file look like before using the `robot_localization` package?

Comment: the before was without robot_localization package.

Comment: The first photo is by the launch file from some gazebo simulation without `robot_localization` package. Understand? than when for the same robot and same simulation I add the` robot_localization` package with the above launch file comes the broken TF as shown in second photo. Is it clear now?

Comment: The second image actually looks correct. You seem to be providing a ground truth transformation / state (1st img, or right tree), but you also want an estimated state, which is the left tree. If you're only fusing an imu, and you've set your "world" frame to odom, you get the left tree. If you have no odometry / velocity / differential inputs, you may statically transform / place the map frame at the same location as the odom frame. If you want a second ground truth frame for your entire robot, you need to publish your robot tfs again, but in that ground truth frame specifically.

Comment: All this depends, of course, on what you want. You want it "fixed", but you haven't described how you're trying to use it, and how it currently is actually "breaks" what you're trying to do.